# ¿Hay algunas diferencias entre "asombrado" y "asombroso"?

Tags: sinónimos

Hay algunas diferencias entre "`asombrado`" y "`asombroso`"?

El inglés traducciones son "astonished, amazed" y "astonishing, amazing" respectivamente.

Comment: Las diferencias en inglés y español son iguales.  "asombrado" describe el observador, y "asombroso" describe lo observado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí, una describe cómo la persona se siente y la otra lo que causa ese sentimiento.

Por ejemplo *amazed* y *amazing* son ambos adjetivos, pero de acuerdo a lo anterior, la terminación *-ed* muestra cómo se siente la persona y la terminación *-ing* muestra la cosa que causa el sentimiento.

> *I was **amazed**. The play was **amazing**.* (*Estaba **asombrado**. La obra fue **asombrosa***.)